# Marklogic: Disabling content processing (CPF) for large updates

Tags: marklogic, pipeline

In my application, documents updated or loaded into MarkLogic are sent through the content processing framework based on document collection.  This triggers an extensive workload including versioning and querying external systems.

Is there a way to temporarily disable the CPF?  I sometimes need to make minor changes to all documents (~300,000) such as adding a new document property.  In these cases, I would prefer the pipelines not to run at all so my system isn't held up for days.

In the past, I've temporarily changed the domain collection names and commented out large sections in the pipeline XML files.  Neither of these solutions is ideal since I have dozens of collections and pipeline XML files.

Answer (score 1):

One possible method is to switch the triggers database to none, and then switch it back when done.  That seems to work for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can always disable the triggers. If you go to the triggers part of the admin for your database, you'll see the triggers for cpf (cpf:create etc.). You can disable them. Then CPF will not run.